# how to center both img and text inside the same div

Tags: html, css, image, text, center

I want to align centered an image and a short text, relative to viewport.
I would like to have the image followed by the text in the same line when it is space enough, like landscape view.
And when isn't enough space for both in the same line, I would like the text to slide under the image, and both to be still centered!
Any ideas will be welcomed.

Comment: You may want to show what you already have (HTML and CSS).

Answer (score 0):

Your request is the basic fundamental reason why the whole area of responsive web pages exist, and mobile first design methodologies ... this is a very very generic question, you need to be more specific ... are you trying to achieve this just with your own html and css ?? are you using any frame works ?? This is standard business as usual for frameworks like Bootstrap3.0 and jQuery. If you have not heard of them, then I would recommend stop trying to re-invent the wheel, get a crash course in Bootstrap3.0 (particularly in the scaffolding, this is how you achieve responsiveness, you can specify css settings for different screen sizes, what is the minimum width of an item, and what to do in the event that this minimum width is crossed ... slide one item under the other ... items can be divs, viewports, ANYTHING)

Comment: I don't use any framework, I believe in that keeping things simple is the best way not to lose control! HTML5 and CSS3 should be enough to achieve such a task.

Comment: I don't think this actually answers any question.

Comment: I am not gonna reinvent the wheel upon request ... wanna figure it out, AT LEAST claim that you have followed some HTML5 and CSS3 webtoolkit tutorials (yeah google that ... and should have figured that much out by your own, even before posting this question) and that your stuck at some point ... At least consider my advise, get the framework, see how it works, & look at its source code (duh !!) but throwing your assignment up here & expecting it to get done is not what stackoverflow is all about ... & yes Daniel ... this is not an answer, its guidance ... ask about an error not a subject